# Referring to data from different table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use join function to match the data in original table by referring to the data from different table. I worked it out, but somehow it drops all data with missing values(NULL) from original table.

The table I am trying to refer to looks like:

```
|seasons| season_num|
---------------------
|spring |    0      |
|summer |    1      |
|fall   |    2      |
|winter |    3      |
|NULL   |    -1     |
```

I only have seasons data in the original table so would like to insert seasons_num info. It matched spring  to winter, but dropped out data with missing information.

Code I came up with:

```
--adding season_num information
select s.*, l.seasons, l.season_num
FROM [A].[dbo].[originaltable] as s
join A.dbo.referringtable as l
on l.seasons=s.seasons_string
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

How do I keep the missing data as well?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `left join` instead of `join`.

Comment: what is structure and data in "dbo.referringtable"?

Comment: @FLICKER dbo.referringtable is just as shown above. I just made an  empty table in sql and copy&pasted info from excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN`in order to include nulls from your original (read: left) table.

```
--adding season_num information
SELECT s.*, l.seasons, l.season_num
FROM [A].[dbo].[originaltable] as s
LEFT JOIN A.dbo.referringtable as l
ON l.seasons=s.seasons_string
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

If you want to match the null values to the reference table, this is one solution. First, modify the reference table to be like this:

```
|seasons| season_num|
---------------------
|spring |    0      |
|summer |    1      |
|fall   |    2      |
|winter |    3      |
|null   |    -1     |
```

Then modify the your original query to coalesce the orignal tables's seasons column to `'null'` in the `ON` clause like so:

```
--adding season_num information
SELECT s.*, l.seasons, l.season_num
FROM [A].[dbo].[originaltable] as s
JOIN A.dbo.referringtable as l
ON l.seasons=COALESCE(s.seasons_string, 'null')
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: I tried... it does keep missing values in original table but don't match the integer -1 from the referring table above.

Comment: You could do a COALESCE on the null values

Comment: ..strange. not working. I will try union function instead..thank you so much!